# How do you execute a template of initial settings the first time you boot a system made in Django

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I need to create a template for the initial settings of the system. The template should appear the first time you boot the system. On subsequent occasions should not appear again this template. Some idea.

Comment: This is over-broad. Can you be more specific? What do you mean by template (template has special meaning in the context of Django). Do you mean project template? Why do you want the behavior of the system (I assume you mean web server) to change after the first boot?

Comment: The first time you boot the system must load the template with forms to create objects of a class. For example, in an academic system must load the first time you boot a form to add the school year and school settings. If these settings are not created should not access the creation of students, courses, etc..

Comment: Why do you mean by "boot the system"? Do you mean start the server, or do you mean connect to the server as a new user?

Comment: I mean, the first time you access the application through the browser